# How to show that a Group is not profinite?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups, profinite-groups

I tried to show that $\mathbb{Z}$ is not profinite.
So I know that a topological group $G$ is profinite if $G\cong \underleftarrow{\lim}~ G/H$, with
$H$ all open normal subgroups of $G$. And I know
that there is no surjective map $\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow\underleftarrow{\lim}~\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.
So $\mathbb{Z}$ is not profinite with the profinite topology.
But how to show that there is no other topology that $\mathbb{Z}$ is profinite?

Comment: I am no expert at all, but this has the feel of a cardinality argument. Do you know if $\lim\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is countable?

Comment: Where did you find this definition of profinite group? It is not the standard one (though it may be equivalent).

Comment: Oh im sorry i have find in Ribes Introduction of Profinite Groups and Galois Cohomology 
that G profinite implies $G\cong\underleftarrow{lim}G/H

Comment: @Cody  Ok, but that's a *property* of profinite groups, it's not the definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reference (the book *Introduction of Profinite Groups and Galois Cohomology* by Ribes) defines a profinite group to be a compact Hausdorff totally disconnected topological group. I'll argue directly from this definition that any profinite group is either finite or has cardinality $\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Suppose $G$ is a profinite group. If $G$ has an isolated point, then every point of $G$ is isolated (since for any  $a\in G$, the map $x\mapsto ax$ is a homeomorphism). But then $\{\{a\}\mid a\in G\}$ is an open cover of $G$, so $G$ is finite by compactness.

Now suppose $G$ has no isolated points (such a space is called *perfect*). It's a standard fact that a perfect locally compact Hausdorff space has cardinality $\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$. But the proof is a bit easier for a compact Hausdorff totally disconnected space, so I'll outline the argument in this case.

We build a complete binary tree of non-empty clopen sets in $G$ by associating to each finite binary sequence $w$ a clopen set $C_w\subseteq G$, such that for any $w$, writing $w0$ and $w1$ for the sequences obtained by extending $w$ by a $0$ and a $1$, respectively, we have $C_{w0}\subseteq C_w$, $C_{w1}\subseteq C_w$, and $C_{w0}\cap C_{w1} = \emptyset$.

We start by associating the empty sequence to all of $G$. Now given $C_w$, since $G$ has no isolated points, $C_w$ has at least two points, $x$ and $y$. Since $G$ is Hausdorff and totally disconnected, there are two complementary clopen sets such that one contains $x$ and the other contains $y$. We define $C_{w0}$ and $C_{w1}$ by intersecting these two clopen sets with $C_w$.

Now for any infinite binary sequence $s$, we can take the intersection of the clopen sets corresponding to the finite initial segments of $s$: $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} C_{s\restriction n}$. By compactness, this intersection is non-empty, so we can pick a point $x_s$ in the intersection. This gives an injective map from the set of infinite binary sequences (equivalently, paths through the complete binary tree we constructed above) to $G$, which shows that $|G|\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Okay thanks, I understand how you construct the binary tree, but what do mean 
with $s\upharpoonright n$ ?

Comment: The restriction of the infinite binary string $s$ to its first $n$ characters. @Cody

Answer (score 4):

An inverse limit of finite groups is either finite or uncountable. $\mathbb Z$ is neither of those.

For the proof, consider an inverse sequence of finite groups:
$$\cdots \xrightarrow{f_i} G_i \xrightarrow{f_{i-1}} \cdots \xrightarrow{f_2} G_2 \xrightarrow{f_1} G_1 \xrightarrow{f_0} G_0
$$

Case 1: Suppose there exists $I$ such that for all $i \ge I$ the map $f_i$ is an isomorphism. Then the inverse limit is isomorphic to $G_I$ and hence is finite.

Case 2: Suppose for all $I$ there exists $i \ge I$ such that the map $f_i$ is not an isomorphism. Thus one can find a subsequence $i_1 < i_2 < i_3 < \ldots$ such that $f_{i_k}$ is $n_k$-to-one where $n_k \ge 2$. Now one uses a Cantor-type diagonalization argument to prove that the inverse limit is uncountable.

**ADDED:** As pointed out in the comment of @AlexKruckman, you can also get exact cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, but that's more than you asked and so is really another question.

Comment: Okay why profinite groups are either finite or uncountable ?

Comment: I added a quick proof.

Comment: I think a diagonalization argument will work to show that the inverse limit is uncountable, but not that the cardinality is exactly $2^{\aleph_0}$. To get the exact cardinality, you can just count the "paths" through the "tree". Also, there are profinite groups of cardinality greater than $2^{\aleph_0}$ (which are inverse limits of uncountable directed systems of finite groups).

Comment: Sorry to continue commenting on this minor point, but regarding your edit: the problem is not just to get an upper bound of $2^{\aleph_0}$, but also a lower bound. "Uncountable" does not imply $\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$ unless you assume the continuum hypothesis. That is, the diagonal argument only gives $\geq \aleph_1$, which is  weaker than $\geq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I reverted my answer to uncountability.